# XAMP: Mysql Connection Stuck

Tags: mysql, xampp

Lately I developed in ASP.NET MVC
after I done my project. When I tried my Xampp today
The Mysql module is the only one not working to the module
the apache module is working on my xampp

why it happens?

I try to change the port of **mysql:3306 to 3308**
then the httpd config I change the **port:80 to port:8080**
but still the xampp says Attempting to start MySQL app...
if i start the mysql module.

Comment: So what does your mysql log file say why it fails to start up?

Comment: their is no update log to the mysql error notepad

Comment: Are you sure? That would mean that the executable does not even start... I suggest you try starting the mysql daemon manually from a console. What happens?

Comment: when i force to start the mysql module it start, then it will changed again to stopped

Comment: With "starting manually" I meant from a console, not by pushing some button. That way you see what it reports.

Comment: when i start manually the only says Attempting to start MySQL app...

Comment: I doubt that, actually. The MySQL daemon executable will _not_ call itself an "app". Not sure what you do, but you do _not_ start the daemon from a shell. So what _do_ you do? Could you please describe?

Comment: Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
4:05:26 PM  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:05:26 PM  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:05:26 PM  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:05:26 PM  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:05:26 PM  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
4:05:26 PM  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: You are still using some frontend for the management, not a console/shell. Giving up.